how do i make my g.drawline draw ontop of my JTextFields in a JFrame
i am attempting to make a soduku solving java program. i want it to be graphical and graphical isnt an area ive really explored before.first ive created a graphics method to draw all my needed lines. I then create JTextFields for text input however these appear ontop of my drawn lines which ruins the look of a soduku. how can i make it such that the lines appear ontop of the text fields?
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
///drawing lines for soduku///
    }

this gives me the correct visual of:
enter image description here
however when i add my text boxes it appears as:
enter image description here
all relevent code for adding the text boxes is in the same class and is as follows:
gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 9));
gridPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(squareSize * 9, squareSize * 9));
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                JTextField textField = new JTextField(1);
                textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                textField.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
                gridPanel.add(textField);
                textFields[i][j] = textField;
            }
        }
this.add(gridPanel); 


directly after this is where i have my paintComponent method. any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated
tried: creating seperate class for lines to draw them in and then adding that into the jpanel as well but i fould this teadious and difficult to do so its possible i did it wrong
i would like: to display my lines each with a textbox inbetween(behind)
result: 4 hours of my time gone and slight loss in sanity without even getting to the point of thinking how on earth a computer efficiently solves a soduku

Most JTextFields come with a javax.swing.border.Border, depending on your look and feel. You can replace this Border object with your own custom border by call myTextField.setBorder(x).
Here is an example of how I would use Borders to achieve a Sudoku look. On my Mac this app looks like this: 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * This contains a 9x9 grid a JTextFields, and they are rendered as if they are in nine 3x3 boxes.
 */
public class SudokuPanel extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        // this is only because on Mac I don't want my bottom window corners rounded
        f.setUndecorated(true);

        f.getContentPane().add(new SudokuPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    JTextField[] cellFields = new JTextField[9 * 9];

    public SudokuPanel() {
        for (int a = 0; a < cellFields.length; a++) {
            cellFields[a] = createTextField();
            int row = a / 9;
            int column = a % 9;
            boolean isTopOfBox = row%3 == 0;
            boolean isBottomOfBox = row%3 == 2;
            boolean isLeftOfBox = column%3 == 0;
            boolean isRightOfBox = column%3 == 2;
            cellFields[a].setBorder(new SudokuCellBorder(isTopOfBox, isLeftOfBox, isBottomOfBox, isRightOfBox));
        }
        layoutGrid(this, 9, cellFields);
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    private JTextField createTextField() {
        JTextField returnValue = new JTextField();
        returnValue.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        returnValue.setFont(returnValue.getFont().deriveFont(26f));
        returnValue.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                changedUpdate(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                changedUpdate(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = returnValue.getText();
                if (text.length() > 1) {
                    String newText = text.substring(text.length() - 1, text.length());
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> returnValue.setText(newText));
                }
            }
        };
        returnValue.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
        return returnValue;
    }

    static void layoutGrid(JPanel container, int numberOfColumns, JComponent... elements) {
        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1; c.weighty = 1; c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        for (int a = 0; a < elements.length; a++) {
            c.gridx = a % numberOfColumns;
            c.gridy = a / numberOfColumns;
            container.add(elements[a], c);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This always paints a light gray 1px border, and it optionally paints a 1px black line on top of the
 * top/right/bottom/left edges.
 */
class SudokuCellBorder implements Border {
    private final boolean isTopOfBox, isLeftOfBox, isBottomOfBox, isRightOfBox;

    public SudokuCellBorder(boolean isTopOfBox, boolean isLeftOfBox, boolean isBottomOfBox, boolean isRightOfBox) {
        this.isTopOfBox = isTopOfBox;
        this.isLeftOfBox = isLeftOfBox;
        this.isBottomOfBox = isBottomOfBox;
        this.isRightOfBox = isRightOfBox;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g.drawRect(x,y,width,height);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        if (isTopOfBox)
            g.drawLine(x, y, x + width, y);
        if (isLeftOfBox)
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + height);
        if (isBottomOfBox)
            g.drawLine(x, y + height, x + width, y + height);
        if (isRightOfBox)
            g.drawLine(x + width , y, x + width, y + height);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(1,1,1,1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }
}

This only presents a basic 9x9 grid of text boxes. If you want to add support for "candidate mode": that gets a little messier. (Personally I'd recommend making each cell a JPanel with a CardLayout that can toggle between a JTextField and some other custom component. There are a lot of ways you could approach it, though.) This basic Border approach should still work whether the cells are JTextFields or some more complicated JComponent.
